# Arrange an array of positive integers to form the largest numerical string

Tags: php, algorithm

Can someone help me for my College Exam. I tried to search but Im totally newbie in php and Im still studying

Here's what i want, Can you give me some Idea or function so that I can arrange an array of positive integers to form the largest numerical string?

For Example:

```
$arrnew = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

assert(getLargestNumStr($arrnew) == 98765432110, 'Basic test 9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-10');
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: how about sorting them as strings and then concatenating them

Comment: I don't mind helping, but I'm not going to do it all for you.

Comment: Can you give me some hint guys? thank you.

Comment: check usort for a custom sort

Comment: What should be the result of [9, 90, 901] ? 990901 or 999100?

Comment: 999100 sir........

Comment: So why you put `Basic test 9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-10`, not `Basic test 9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-1-0`? If that the case just reorder the digit in the string/number should do, the array requirement is ridiculous

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice problem, this could be solved by this observation:

- let's consider two elements in the array `x` and `y`, so assume that for the two numbers created by appending these two elements: `xy > yx` => in the final result, `x` will always be in front of `y`, otherwise, we could easily create a larger number by swapping the position of `x` and `y` in the result.

=> We could simply create a custom sort based on this observation, when compare two number `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting the array in descending order with something like [arsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) and concatinate the Array-elements to a string. This should give you the highest possible number.

Comment: What is the result of the case [100,1000, 10000]?

Comment: @Pham Trung I see what you did there. I initially thought about digits, not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with below code if it solve your problem...

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$text='';
foreach($array as $arr){
    $text.=$arr;
}

$string = str_split($text, "1"); 
$new_text = implode(",", $string); 
$output=explode(",",$new_text); 

rsort($output);
$final = '';
foreach($output as $out){
    $final.=$out;   
}   

echo $final;
```

Comment: Thank you..... But Im gonna study this first so that I know how you do it.. thank you again.

Comment: Simple test case for you [9, 90, 901], your answer should be 990901

Comment: This is wrong , for case [9, 90, 901], it give 999100 which is just making use of each digit in the element.

Comment: @PhamTrung requirement is for answer 999100 only

Comment: So please explain why OP puts `Basic test 9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-10`, not `Basic test 9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-1-0` in the description?

Comment: it's worked for @RikataOnimore, it solved the problem

Comment: I am just helping @RikataOnimore

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$arrnew = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
arsort($arrnew);
$str = str_replace(',','',join(',',$arrnew));
$arr1 = str_split($str);
arsort($arr1);
print_r($arr1);
echo implode('',$arr1);
```

[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xfjf-046e)